# how to delete character which inserted automatically

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-c++, abbreviations

I have the following mapping in my vimrc

```
inoremap < <><left>
```

but this statement conflicts with

```
iabbrev cout cout<<
```

and in insert mode I get `cout<<>>`

how to delete `>>` characters automatically

Answer (score 1):

You should use `:inoreab` instead of `:iab`. `nore` avoids mappings/abbreviations from being triggered.

Another possibility is to have the mapping analyse the context. IIRC, in [lh-cpp/lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) I only expand `<` into `<|>` when I detect `#include` or `template` on the same line.